# Can I remove this promotion "SmartTarget Meta Promotion (do not remove!)"?

Tags: smarttarget

Every Fredhopper instance in a SDL SmartTarget setup has one promotion named `SmartTarget Meta Promotion (do not remove!)`. This promotions contains the medata SmartTarget uses to order the promotions and obviously -thoug tempting- this prmotion must not be removed.

Now I am cleaning up a Fredhopper instance to repurpose it, the instance is reindexed to clean all items, removing all promotions, etc. Can I safely remove this meta promotion as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the name points, you *should not* remove or edit any SmartTarget Promotions within Fredhopper unless there is no other option. This is also the reason they are hidden by default.

In most cases you should be able to load the list of Promotions within SmartTarget and delete the Promotions from there. That will ensure that the Meta Promotion is up-to-date and you don't lose any data.

That said, if you are deleting **all** Promotions using the Business Manager, then yes you can remove the Meta Promotion too. Just make sure that you delete all of the Promotions permanently (first from the main list and then from the trash) as items in the trash are still returned by the API.

Comment: Indeed the SmartTarget promotions are hidden by default. I reveiled them by applying this config: https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/94bcf7d9c10ec04c8925